# Filter nested array inside different objects and return object with new filtered array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have objects containing arrays Im hoping to filter. I would like to filter an array of classes based on category and division and then return the new object(s) with the filtered arrays.

Here is what the JSON looks like:

```
    { "monday": [
    { "id": 1, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "jazz", "division": "junior" },
    { "id": 2, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "tap", "division": "senior" },
    { "id": 3, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "hip hop", "division": "teen" }
  ],
  "tuesday": [
    { "id": 1, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "jazz", "division": "teen" },
    { "id": 2, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "tap", "division": "teen" },
    { "id": 3, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "hip hop", "division": "teen" }
  ],
  "wednesday": [
    { "id": 1, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "tap", "division": "teen" },
    { "id": 2, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "jazz", "division": "teen" },
    { "id": 3, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "hip hop", "division": "teen" }
  ]
}
```

And this is the react code for filtering and mapping over the filtered array.

```
const [classes, setClasses] = useState(data);
  const [category, setCategory] = useState(category);
  const [division, setDivision] = useState(division);

  useEffect(() => {
    let filteredClasses = data;
    if (category !== 'all') {
      filteredClasses = filteredClasses.filter(
        (classes) => classes.category === category
      );
    }
    if (division !== 'all') {
      filteredClasses = filteredClasses.filter(
        (classes) => classes.division === division
      );
    }
    setClasses(filteredClasses);
  }, [category, division]);
     <ul>
            {classes.monday.map((item) => (
              <li key={item.order}>
                {item.time} <br />
                {item.class} <br />
                {item.age}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
          <ul>
            {classes.tuesday.map((item) => (
              <li key={item.order}>
                {item.time} <br />
                {item.class} <br />
                {item.age}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're not returning the jsx nor the map function. Can you try that out??

Comment: Sorry I see how that’s confusing. I clipped the return part from the code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to call `filter()` on the outer `classes` Object rather on the individual property Arrays. In that case you will need to iterate over the [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) of the containing object and filter each referenced array in turn.

Here is an example calling [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on the array of keys returned by `Object.keys()` and assigning the result of [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) back to the same key in the accumulator.

```js
const classes = { "monday": [{ "id": 1, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "jazz", "division": "junior" }, { "id": 2, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "tap", "division": "senior" }, { "id": 3, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "hip hop", "division": "teen" }], "tuesday": [{ "id": 1, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "jazz", "division": "teen" }, { "id": 2, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "tap", "division": "teen" }, { "id": 3, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "hip hop", "division": "teen" }], "wednesday": [{ "id": 1, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "tap", "division": "teen" }, { "id": 2, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "jazz", "division": "teen" }, { "id": 3, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "hip hop", "division": "teen" }] }

const division = 'all';
const category = 'jazz';

const filteredClasses = Object.keys(classes)
  .reduce((acc, day) => {
    acc[day] = classes[day].filter(_class =>
      (division === 'all' || _class.division === division)
      && (category === 'all' || _class.category === category));

    return acc;
  }, {});

console.log(filteredClasses)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

And here is an example using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and moving the `filter()` call into a separate function.

```js
const classes = { "monday": [{ "id": 1, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "jazz", "division": "junior" }, { "id": 2, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "tap", "division": "senior" }, { "id": 3, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "hip hop", "division": "teen" }], "tuesday": [{ "id": 1, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "jazz", "division": "teen" }, { "id": 2, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "tap", "division": "teen" }, { "id": 3, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "hip hop", "division": "teen" }], "wednesday": [{ "id": 1, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "tap", "division": "teen" }, { "id": 2, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "jazz", "division": "teen" }, { "id": 3, "time": "sometime", "class": "some class", "age": "12", "category": "hip hop", "division": "teen" }] }

const division = 'all';
const category = 'jazz';

const filterClassArray = (arr) => (
  arr.filter(_class =>
    (division === 'all' || _class.division === division)
    && (category === 'all' || _class.category === category)
  ));

const filteredClasses = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.keys(classes).map(day => [day, filterClassArray(classes[day])]
  ));

console.log(filteredClasses)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Kudos pilchard, exactly what I was after! Works perfectly.